# Error: String must be an atomic vector R

Tags: r, vector

I am new to R, and I am having trouble using stringr on a dataset. I am trying to subset the data by variables with the word restaurant in them against those with out. I constantly get this error message.

```
str_detect(matrix(expandedDataFrame[1,12:21],1,
                 ncol(expandedDataFrame[,12:21])),"Restaurants")
Error: String must be an atomic vector
```

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No it should be any atomic vector.  For example: `str_detect(diag(2),"1")` works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get an error because `str_detect` is expecting an `atomic` type as first argument. I guess that if you use `as.matrix` and not `matrix` your code will work.

Indeed:

```
is.atomic(matrix(data.frame(c=1:10,c1=5:1)))
[1] FALSE
> is.atomic(as.matrix(data.frame(c=1:10,c1=5:1)))
[1] TRUE
```

So your code becomes:

```
str_detect(as.matrix(expandedDataFrame[1,12:21],1,
                 ncol(expandedDataFrame[,12:21])),"Restaurants")
```

But since you don't give a reproducible example, this is just a guess....

Comment: Thanks! that worked! I am pretty new, so thanks again for your help.